# T-SQL Query comparing Member counts between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

**TABLE 1**: Data sent to vendor

```
| MemberID | FirstName | LastName | Etc |
| :------: | :-------: | :------: | :-: |
| 1        | John      | Smith    | Etc |
| 2        | Jane      | Doe      | Etc |
| 3        | Dan       | Laren    | Etc |
```

**TABLE 2**: Data returned from vendor

```
| MemberID | FirstName | LastName | Etc |
| :------: | :-------: | :------: | :-: |
| 1        | John      | Smith    | Etc |
| 2        | Jane      | Doe      | Etc |
| 3        | Dan       | Laren    | Etc |
```

We send data to a vendor which is used for their matching algorithm and they return the data with new information. The members are matched with a MemberID data element. How would I write a query which shows me which MemberIDs we sent to the vendor but the vendor didn't return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT EXITS` would be my first choice here.

**Example**

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 A
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Table2 B
                   WHERE  A.MemberID = B.MemberID )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MemberID
FROM Table1
WHERE MemberID NOT IN (SELECT MemberID FROM Table2)
```

Comment: NOT IN could get expensive.   Perhaps you should consider NOT EXISTS  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Answer (score 0):

Using EXCEPT is one option.

```
SELECT sent.[MemberID] FROM Tbl1_SentToVendor       sent
EXCEPT
SELECT recv.[MemberID] FROM Tbl2_ReturnedFromVendor recv
```

This is just on `MemberID`, but the "`EXCEPT`" syntax can also support additional columns (e.g., in case you want to filter out data that may be the same as what you already have.)

Comment: In a relative to the batch comparison, NOT EXISTS was 27% while EXCEPT was 73%